# Finding out the greatest among the available dates for a record, then mapping the output to other similar outputs to find the greatest among all

Tags: php, mysql, date, zend-framework2, union-all

I have 6 tables, with **account** as common key in 5 of these tables and **id** being the common key for all these tables.

5 of which have 4-5 date fields. Now, my task is to find the greatest date available for a record in a table using the where condition: **id** = 10. Now similarly find the greatest date for the same record in all the other tables. In all the tables there is no such constraint like the **account** has to be the same number, it can be different for the same **id** in all the different tables.

Now I have to find the corresponding **account** which has the max. date value amongst all corresponding to the **id** value passed.

Please Help!!

Comment: Can you put the table data, like tbl_name, fields.. and 1 row as example for every table. Also do you what the query?the php? or the zf2 code?

Comment: I just want the query structure, that's why I provided examples of the elements I am using.. "account" and "id". I am not good at Union, so couldn't implement the same.

Comment: TABLE 'A' fields : id ; date1 ; date2 ; date3 ; date4 ; date5 ; account
Similar table structure for TABLE 'B' , TABLE 'C' , TABLE 'D' and TABLE 'E'.

Comment: so you need the highest column date?

Comment: TABLE 'A' fields : id ; date1 ; date2 ; date3 ; date4 ; date5 ; account 
Similar table structure for TABLE 'B' , TABLE 'C' , TABLE 'D' , TABLE 'E' and for TABLE 'F' : id ; date1 ; date2 ; date3 ; date4 ; date5
Now id in TABLE 'F' is the primary key.. and has to be passed by the user, which is unique for all the records. but the corresponding account may not be the same. I need to find in which table the date has the highest value, and the corresponding account.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    max(convert varchar, acct.account_date, 101)
FORM
    account acct
WHERE 
    acct.id = (SELECT acct.id FROM id_tlb WHERE acct.id = 'something')
```

you'ld probably won't need to convert date there, but it'll help you get `mm/dd/yyyy` format for timestamp.

Reply back, if you need something else.

Comment: the table has 5 date columns. and he needs the max of the 5 columns but also the max of the 5 tables. So at least union is needed, the problem is how to get the maximum column.

Comment: I want to find the max available date from all the records first.., for the five tables. And then find the max among all of them. And then display the corresponding account value.

Comment: union'd be too expensive and reduce the performance, i guess. I'd use a stored proc/function. Maybe i'd process each row meeting the where condition and find the max there, until i find the max, i require. See if it helps. Anyway, stored proc are more scalable regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.. the query looks bad because I think the table design/requirement conflict.

```
select max(dateB) AS max_date FROM
(
    select max(dateA) AS dateB FROM 
    (   
        select date1 AS dateA  from tb1 where id = 10
        union 
        select date2 AS dateA from tb1 where id = 10
        union 
        select date3 AS dateA from tb1 where id = 10
        union 
        select date4 AS dateA from tb1 where id = 10
    )
    UNION 
    select max(dateA) AS dateB FROM 
    (   
        select date1 AS dateA  from tb2 where id = 10
        union 
        select date2 AS dateA from tb2 where id = 10
        union 
        select date3 AS dateA from tb2 where id = 10
        union 
        select date4 AS dateA from tb2 where id = 10
    )
    UNION 
    select max(dateA) AS dateB FROM 
    (   
        select date1 AS dateA  from tb3 where id = 10
        union 
        select date2 AS dateA from tb3 where id = 10
        union 
        select date3 AS dateA from tb3 where id = 10
        union 
        select date4 AS dateA from tb3 where id = 10
    )
    UNION 
    select max(dateA) AS dateB FROM 
    (   
        select date1 AS dateA  from tb4 where id = 10
        union 
        select date2 AS dateA from tb4 where id = 10
        union 
        select date3 AS dateA from tb4 where id = 10
        union 
        select date4 AS dateA from tb4 where id = 10
    )
)
```

Comment: Yes. Every Union operation will take much time. I am still looking for a better optimized query for the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes got it finally.

select date1 , account from table1 where id = 'X'
union all
select date2 , account from table1 where id = 'X'
union all
select date3 , account from table1 where id = 'X'
union all
select date4 , account from table2 where id = 'X'
union all
select date5 , account from table2 where id = 'X'
union all
select date6 , account from table2 where id = 'X'
union all
select date7 , account from table3 where id = 'X'
union all

### select date8 , account from table3 where id = 'X'

### ------

### ------

order by date1 desc limit 1;

Hope this will help others now.